# Opening on-screen keyboard written in JQuery with angularjs directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, on-screen-keyboard

I'm trying to write a directive in angularJS which allow to open this https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/ on-screen keyboard on click a button or image. So far I made based on this topic : [Update AngularJS models from a jQuery plugin with a "on change" callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547152/update-angularjs-models-from-a-jquery-plugin-with-a-on-change-callback), directive which open a keyboard on click at input field. Can anyone help me with it ?

```
app.directive('keyboard',function(){
  return {
    require : '?ngModel',
    restrict : 'C',
    link : function(scope,element,attrs,ngModelCtrl){
      if(!ngModelCtrl){
        return;
      }

      $(element).keyboard({
        stickyShift: false,
        usePreview: false,
        autoAccept: true,

        change: function(e, kb, el) {
            if(!scope.$$phase && !scope.$root.$$phase)
            {
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(el.value);
                }); 
            }
        }
    });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just bind jQuery click event in link function:

```
element.click(function(){
    element.getkeyboard().reveal();
});
```